# Golang Gorm: Is it possible to Update a record via many2many relationship? why where caluse in not working in Child Table..?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

```
func (u *userEnitity) EditUser(emplyeeCode string, user models.User) (models.User, int, string) {
    var tx *gorm.DB
    var statusCode = 200
    var errText string
    var count int64
    var id int
    var roleId []int
    count = 0
    if tx = u.resource.Select("id").Model(&models.User{}).Where("employee_code = ? ", emplyeeCode).Scan(&id).Count(&count); tx.Error != nil {
        return user, statusCode, errText
    }
    if count == 0 {

        return user, 400, "User does not exist"
    }

    u.resource.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(models.User{
        FirstName:  user.FirstName,
        MiddleName: user.MiddleName,
        LastName:   user.LastName,
        MobileNo:   user.MobileNo,
        Email:      user.Email,
    })
    if tx = u.resource.Table("user_role").Select("role_id").Where("user_id = ?", id).Scan(&roleId); tx.Error != nil {
        return user, statusCode, errText
    }


    u.resource.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Where("id = ?", roleId).Association("Roles").Replace(&user.Roles)
    return user, statusCode, errText
}

type User struct {
    ID           int       `json:"id,omitempty" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    EmployeeCode string    `json:"employee_code,omitempty" gorm:"unique"`
    FirstName    string    `json:"first_name" validate:"required,max=50" `
    MiddleName   string    `json:"middle_name,omitempty" validate:"max=50"`
    LastName     string    `json:"last_name" validate:"required,max=50" `
    MobileNo     string    `json:"mobile_no" validate:"required,max=10,numeric"`
    Email        string    `json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
    Password     string    `json:"-" `
    Status       string    `json:"status,omitempty" `
    CreatedAt    time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    Roles        []Role    `json:"roles" gorm:"many2many:user_role" `
}
type Role struct {
    ID              int    `json:"id,omitempty" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    RoleName        string `json:"role_name" validate:"required,max=50" gorm:"unique"`
    RoleDescription string `json:"role_description" validate:"required,max=150"`
    Status          string `json:"status"`
}
```

Comment: could you please add code for your `User` and `Role` structs?

Comment: I Have added user and Role Struct

Comment: This might be related to the following: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3487